# How to retrieve object by foreign key in the url using Django and rest_framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I'm using the two simple models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey("Country")

class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

To retrieve an object by it's primary key I defined views and urls like this ([related to my resolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509087/how-to-get-a-response-of-multiple-objects-using-rest-framework-and-django/)):

```
url(r'^location/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.LocationDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='location-detail'),
url(r'^country/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.CountryDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='country-detail')
```

Now I like to define a new view which returns me a list of all locations/cities which are in a country. My idea is to use the folling url definition (or similar).

```
url(r'^location-by-country/(?P<country_pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.LocationByCountryListAPIView.as_view(), name='location-by-country-detail')
```

I was searching for an answer for a while, but probably I'm not using the right keywords. How would I implement my view to use a foreign key from the url? Could I use filters to filter locations by the country_pk?

Edit: This is what I came up with, but I don't know how to filter for the foreign key:

```
class LocationByCountryIdAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):        
    def get(self, request, country_pk):
        locations = Location.objects.all() # .filter(???)
        location_list = list()
        for location in locations:
            # now I would do something similar to this
            # or use a filter on locations instead of creating location_list 
            # and appending locations to it
            if location.country.pk == country_pk:
                location_list.append(location)        

        location_serializer = LocationSerializer(location_list, many=True)
        # or location_serializer = LocationSerializer(locations, many=True) when using filter

        return Response({
            'locations': location_serializer.data
        })
```

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I got it running by my self. Here's how it goes:

```
class LocationByCountryListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get(self, request, country_pk):
        # get the country by its primary key from the url
        country = Country.objects.get(pk=country_pk)

        locations = Location.objects.filter(country=country)
        location_serializer = LocationSerializer(locations, many=True)

        return Response({
            'locations': location_serializer.data
        })
```

I'm using the url definition as mentioned above:

```
url(r'^location-by-country/(?P<country_pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.LocationByCountryListAPIView.as_view(), name='location-by-country-detail')
```

Anyway, I'm not sure if this solution is the best way to do it. I would appreciate any advices how to improve my solution.

Best regards,
Michael